# How to fetch data from mysql to XML File

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Im a Amateur in PHP but i have to build a Website with Google Maps API.

I build it with the informations from here: [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps#echoxml)

The Data with the coordinates is saved in a Table in my Mysql DB. 
At this moment i have to run manually a PHP file, which generates / echo a XML on the browser, which i have to save in my htdocs directory. 
In a JS script i run a function, which loads the data from the XML for showing the addresses on the map.

The goal is, that i dont have to run manually this PHP file which generates a XML, which i also have to save it manually to the htdocs directory.

This is where im echo'ing de XML Data to the browser:

```html
// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . $row['id'] . '" ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}
// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

How can i do this process outomatically? It should be possible but i found nothing on Google.. I searched for "php fetch from mysql to xml" etc. and found alot about how to fetch data from XML to Mysql.

I hope you are able to understand my bad english.

Greetings

Comment: What do you mean by automatically?

Comment: if i open the URL of the Website, it should build a XML-File with the data from MySql. Because if somebody update some Data in the DB, i have to be sure that Google Maps shows all the actual Addresses.

Comment: Then I assume you will have to get javascript to ask using AJAX for this data every XX seconds so it gets refreshed on your page. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Its not necessary to have 100% actual Data on my Website. In this moment, my website doesnt create this XML automatically. Before i open my website, i have to run manually the php file, then save the output (with xml data) to my htdocs directory AND THEN i can open my website. i just need to find something which doesnt echo the XML-Data....something that write this format to a xml-file.

Comment: @RomanKrattiger You could use require('PAGE URL') in php, this way you would call that php file from another php file to process the script without needing to manually call it each time. Is this what you needed?

Comment: @GrandIQ, yes i know that. But how can i get a XML-File instead of echo'ing the XML-Data to the browser?

Comment: @RomanKrattiger So basically you want to write or create a new file on the server each time this is requested?

Comment: @GrandIQ yes, correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the XML file you requested, you would need to write/create the file each time on request.

```
// This creates the userinfo.xml file and 'w' writes to it.
$xmlfile = fopen("userinfo.xml", "w"); 
$userData = "USER INFORMATION GOES HERE";
fwrite($xmlfile,$userData);
fclose($xmlfile);
```

This function will override the file named "userinfo.xml" if it exists and override it with the information passed with $userData, so be cautious before handling writing files.

Comment: Ok, thank you Sir! But one question...And how can i get the currently output (xml data) to this $userData file? Can i replace the "echo" in my Loop with something that creates my formatted text?

Comment: @RomanKrattiger Store your text information that you have inside of each Echo into a String, like $userData, then pass it as a parameter when your creating the file in fwrite.

Comment: Ok, i will try it. Thanks alot for your help Sir!

Comment: @RomanKrattiger Your welcome! If this answer helped you don't forget to mark it as Correct/Answer, Thanks!